# invoice2data format matching number

Tags: invoice2data

I'm using [invoice2data](https://github.com/invoice-x/invoice2data/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md) to match specific values from an invoice PDF. However, it seems that some values are extracted without decimals and I don't know why. When I run invoice2data I get `'amount': 118989.0` instead of `'amount': 1 189,89`

Regex: `Total \/ Brutto\s*(?:.*?\b(\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3})*,\d{1,2})\b){2}`

Text:

```
Cota TVA % / VAT %                Net / Net      TVA / VAT       Total / Brutto

                                                                          19,0        1 189,89           226,08            1 415,97
                                                                                              Total / Total amount         1 415,97`
```

Do you know why?

[Demo](http://regexr.com/64v0l)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I should've read the documentation thoroughly. All I had to do was to change the decimal separator option

```
options:
  remove_whitespace: false
  decimal_separator: ','      // THIS
```